# How do I keep aspect ratio with padding for a card image on mobile display?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

When I add padding around an image at the top of a card when in dev tools mobile view, the image doesn't keep aspect ratio. When I go back to full size view the aspect ratio is fine.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card bg-primary product-card--style mb-3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x500/8A8A8A/fff" alt="asdf" class="card-img-top product-card--img p-5">
    <div class="card-body product-card--layout">
      <h5 class="card-title">Product 1</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle">For people who..</h6>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias sit illo eaque nulla aliquid tempora sapiente minus consequuntur atque! Iusto.</p>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">More info</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My [code](https://codepen.io/asdfractal/pen/pqWaeX)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/627ii.jpg) of how it looks in dev tool mobile

The thing is if I go to my code pen in dev tools mobile view it seems to be working as it should, but from my file it isn't. This is the reason I'm so confused about it.

Comment: How are you adding the padding? Can you put that in your code?

Comment: It is using bootstrap class "p-5" on the img, but the same result if I add it with my own class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wanted to maintain aspect ratios, does this work for you ?

```css
.card { display:block !important; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card bg-primary product-card--style mb-3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x500/8A8A8A/fff" alt="asdf" class="card-img-top product-card--img p-5">
    <div class="card-body product-card--layout">
      <h5 class="card-title">Product 1</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle">For people who..</h6>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias sit illo eaque nulla aliquid tempora sapiente minus consequuntur atque! Iusto.</p>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">More info</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you.
Are you able to explain why it happened on dev tool on my machine, but through codepen it wasn't? I'm very new to web development so it might be obvious but I'm unable to see why.

Comment: When designing and changing CSS properties, it is a must to do a hard refresh Ctrl+R or Ctrl+F5 of your browser after every change... Chrome/Firefox rely of cache to serve pages faster and changes are left behind; you can do inspector element(F12) to see the exact state of a file on your machine.